# Drawing selected state on custom UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uikit, uitableview, drawrect

I have a customer `UITableViewCell` whose whole display is drawn in`drawRect`.  When it draws it creates `CGLayers` so that it can reuse certain pieces when something is changed.

I have changed my `UITableViewCellSelectionStyle` to "None" because I don't want the default selected view to cover my drawing.

My problem is that I call `setNeedsDisplay` in `setSelected:animated:` for my cell but by the time `drawRect` is called, `setSelected:animated:` has already been called again to deselect the cell.  In my table view controller `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, I call `deselectRowAtIndexPath` as Apple advises.

EDIT - I have also tried called the setNeedsDisplay on my cell from my table view controller's `(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` but that didn't change anything.

Any ideas?   Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the table cell's `selectedBackgroundView` property. If you assign a custom view to that, it'll get shown and hidden at the same time as the default selection backgrounds—in other words, without having to wait for the `setNeedsDisplay` to get around to calling `drawRect:` on the cell itself.

Comment: I tried using this before, but It was only for the purpose of drawing a gradient behind other CALayers.  Can't believe that I forgot about this.  Thanks.